# How do you find the minimum value of $\sqrt{50x^{2}-12800x+820000}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you find the minimum value of the equation above without calculus or graphing? Since the lowest value of a square root is zero, I set the equation above to zero but ended up getting a negative discriminant.

Comment: Try putting x = 128

Comment: use the axis of symmetry equation given by $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$. This gives the minimum value of your quadratic which is also the minimum value of your function. If its negative, ignore it and note that your quadratic approaches positive infinity so it will be equal to zero at some point. (which means your min value is zero). Otherwise, that $x$ value will give you the vertex which is also the minimum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, let's begin by rewriting it. Note that $\sqrt{50x^2-12800x+820000}$ is minimized when $50x^2-12800x+820000$ is minimized*, so we'll temporarily ignore the square root.

We have $$50x^2-12800x+820000$$ 
$$=50(x^2-256x+128^2)+(820,000-50(128)^2)$$
$$=50(x-128)^2+800$$

The minimum value of this quadratic, therefore, is $800$.

And so, the minimum value of $\sqrt{50x^2-12800x+820000}$ is $\sqrt{800}=\boxed{20\sqrt{2}}$

*It is only minimized if this quadratic is positive for all real $x$. Otherwise, the minimum, as you suggested, would be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The vertex of the parabola $y = ax^2 + bc + c$ occurs at $x =  -b/2a = 128$. Substitute that value for $x$, find $y$ and take the square root. Factoring out $50$ and paying attention to $b=128$ will save you some arithmetic.

Comment: i'm literally dumb for not thinking of that +1

Comment: @SakethMalyala No, not dumb at all. Many math problems look easy _after_ you see a solution.